# What is the best way to point the user to another page within the app?

Tags: navigation, user-expectation

For example, after paying for an item, there's a receipt or a QR code that the user would need to access in the near future (imagine booking a cinema ticket and receiving the ticket with QR code).

Now after the checkout, the user is told that the QR code / receipt has been sent to his / her email. **"But alternatively, it can be viewed [location in the app]"**.

What is the best way to show the user where is this location in the app? Usually, I would see that the app would mention the path e.g. **"But alternatively, it can be viewed on Profile > Purchases > Receipts"**.

However, is there a better way of doing this? As some users may not readily find it just by text instruction, especially if it is 2-3 levels deep (like in the above example).

Comment: Needing to point them to where it is should be your first clue that it is perhaps in the wrong place. If the feature is important it should be prominent.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Evil Closet Monkey. If this problem is taking up a lot of time to solve, then maybe re-look at the design. Maybe it is not in the best place it should be.

If i understand correctly, a similar problem also exists with online cab booking, air ticket booking, hotel booking apps. Most of these have a "My bookings" section somewhere in the menu. And this might be the most logical and intuitive place to have it.

With that said, I think you would not have to explicitly mention that users can access it via the my bookings section

Answer (score 1):

I would display the receipt or QR code immediately with the notification that it's also been send to their email address and it can be found in [app directory]. JustAnotherPM's suggestion about having a My bookings section is a great suggestion since these ticket receipts are too important to be put 2-3 levels deep.

This allows users to use the ticket immediately when purchasing it in the cinema lobby for example, while also ensuring them it can be retrieved easily and a backup is send to their email.